# Is there difference between return with await or without

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I'm just thinking about we need to use the await operator, and what is the difference between the following two case.

one

```
public async updateOne(Model, doc, errorMsg?){
    return await Model.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': doc._id}, {'$set': doc}, {upsert:true, new: true}).lean().exec();
}
```

two

```
public updateOne(Model, doc, errorMsg?){
    return Model.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': doc._id}, {'$set': doc}, {upsert:true, new: true}).lean().exec();
}
```

I think there is no difference in the result, but I think it is completely unnecessary to use the async await, because a promise will be returned, and we only need to use the await operator when we call the updateOne function inside an async function.

Comment: Yes, if you are just `await`ing to return a promise, it's redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Oyverus answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233635/1318694), there's no difference in the result but using `async` functions will create another Promise, I've added some rough examples to each case.

Using `async updateOne(){ return await Model.findOneAndUpdate(...) }` results in Promise code something like:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Model.findOneAndUpdate(...).then(resolve, reject)
})
```

Then `async updateOne(){ return Model.findOneAndUpdate(...) }` is:

```
return new Promise(resolve => resolve(Model.findOneAndUpdate(...))
```

A plain `updateOne(){ return Model.findOneAndUpdate(...) }` is:

```
return Model.findOneAndUpdate(...)
```

I tend to use the plain return when possible, but leave an `/*async*/` in the code for documentation purposes.

```
/*async*/ write(){
  return this.db.write()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this use case, there isn't a difference in the eventual result, but there is a difference in how it works.

Returning an awaited promise in an async function will return another promise that gets resolved with the value of the awaited promise, which is basically two promises, which in this use case is redundant, since you're not doing any extra processing on the promise.

Returning a promise in a regular function will just return that promise as is, and won't wrap it around another promise, so you're completely right that it is unnecessary to use async await in this way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there difference between return with await or without? ... I think there is no difference in the result

Yup, you got it right. In your example there is no difference.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> When an async function is called, it returns a Promise. When the async function returns a value, the Promise will be resolved with the returned value.  When the async function throws an exception or some value, the Promise will be rejected with the thrown value.
>
> An async function can contain an await expression, that pauses the execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and returns the resolved value.

---

> we only need to use the await operator when we call the updateOne function inside an async function.

Not exactly, the `async` operator just enables the use of `await` within the corresponding function and all the `await` operator does within that async function is unwrap a promise to the value it would return within the `.then(value => /* do stuff with value */)` callback. The purpose is so the code resembles a more familiar synchronous control flow.

The result of any invocation of a `async` function (i.e. the return type of it) will be a Promise of whatever you returned but note you can still use unwrapped promises (i.e. without `await`) within `async` functions, the values will just be wrapped in promises.

Let me know if you still need help understanding. I'll revise this post.

```js
function simplePromise() { return Promise.resolve('resolved value'); }

async function asyncAwaitTest() {
  const simplePromiseValue = await simplePromise();
  console.log(simplePromiseValue); // resolved value
  
  // if you don't use the `await` keyword, then the promise will still be a promise
  simplePromise().then(value => console.log(value));
}

asyncAwaitTest();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only diffrent is memory usage, which `return await` use more since an intermediate Promise object might be created.

The other good thing about Async/Await is that it allows us to catch any unexpected errors in a good old try/catch block. We just need to wrap our await calls like this:

```
async function doSomethingAsync(){
    try {
    // This async call may fail.
    let result = await someAsyncCall();
    }
    catch(error) {
    // If it does we will catch the error here.
    }  
}
```

The catch clause will handle errors provoked by the awaited asynchronous calls or any other failing code we may have written inside the try block.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you don't need to use an `async` function when the only  return value is the result of applying an `await` operator.  Returning the promise operand of the `await` from a synchronous function that does not use `await` elsewhere is equivalent (as you coded in example "two").

The logic chain of

> we only need to use the await operator when we call the updateOne function inside an async function

however is not exact. You can return the promise from within an async function *without* using `await` as in

three

```
public async updateOne(Model, doc, errorMsg?){
    return Model.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': doc._id}, {'$set': doc}, {upsert:true, new: true}).lean().exec();
}
```

where the promise returned by `Model` will be used to resolve the promise returned by `async`.